# Angular ngif rules

Tags: angular

I would like to remove the *ngif rules that checks editable (true/false) and always display this span but when I remove that rule it still functions the same way

> Am I using the correct syntax?

```
<a *ngIf="editable" (click)="editSection()" style="margin-left: 5px">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list clickable-icon">
</span>
</a>
```

Changed

```
   <a (click)="editSection()" style="margin-left: 5px">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list clickable-icon"></span>
   </a>
```

Comment: Try clearing the cache and running the App again. Also try running it in Incognito Mode.

Comment: Yes, but you could've `ngIf`'d a parent element or your SSR did not render those elements. Like others have stated, make sure you actually rebuilt your app and your browser is not caching.

Comment: Yeah, make sure you actually built, deployed, and refreshed it.

Answer (score 0):

Incognito Mode worked so it was an problem with the cache